# Constructing a matrix of images sorted according to RGB intensity

Tags: image, matlab

I have a set of images like this:

[image]

and I would like to sort them out in a matrix similar to this:

[image: Colour squares]

How do I do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps you can follow.

```
1.Store the values as a matrix

2. Convert the rgb values to hsv colorspace using rgb2hsv function.

Example: C = rgb2hsv(C);

3. Then sort by hue first then by value

Example: C = sortrows(C, [-1 -3 2]);  %# sort first by Hue, then by value

4. Convert it back to rgb

Exmaple : C = hsv2rgb(C);
```

Comment: Thanks for the method. I am new to matlab so please forgive my lack of understanding. When you mention storing the values as a matrix, did you mean storing all images as a single array? If not, I think we're not on the same page. Please see the edited question

Comment: that's right.. store the values in an array.. rgb value of a image returns 1x3 matrix.. add up all the image values into a matrix.